# p5.js: Why is my ellipse flashing?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have an ellipse that scales through draw(), but for some reason, it flashes uncontrollably. I can't seem to figure out why. I suspect it has to do with setTimeout. I need it because I need to wait 10 seconds before drawing the ellipse Here's the code:

```
//diameter of ellipse that increments
var dia1 = 0;
var dia2 = 0;

function setup() {
createCanvas(400,400);
stroke(255);
noFill();
frameRate(40);
}  

//draw and increment ellipse
function circle1() {  
ellipse(width/2,height/2, dia1,dia1);

dia1 = dia1+1;
if (dia1 >= width) {
  dia1 = 0;
}

}
function circle2() {  
ellipse(width/2,height/2, dia2,dia2);
dia2 = dia2+1;
if (dia2 >= width) {
  dia2 = 0;
}

}



function draw() {


background(40,40,40);

//wait 10 seconds before drawing ellipse
setTimeout(function() { circle1(); }, 10000);

circle2();


console.log(dia1);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `setTimeout()` to call drawing functions.

If you want to do timing, use the `millis()` function. More info is available in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/millis), but a basic program would look like this:

```
function draw(){
   background(0);
   if(millis() > 10000){
      ellipse(width/2, height/2, 25, 25);
   }
}
```